# Kendoui Grid and Spring Data Rest ServerSide sorting & pagination

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, spring-data-rest

Had a tough time with this so thought I would ask for a better solution than mine and also be able to post an answer for those it might help.

**Problem:**
Working with KendoUI JSP Grid.  Goal add server side pagination and sorting
I need to be able to have a GET request as follows:

*URL Expected by Spring Data Rest*

`http://localhost:8080/api/accounts?page=1&size=20&sort=firstName,desc -> or asc`

*URL Presented by default from KendoUI*

`http://localhost:8080/api/accounts?take=20&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=20&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=firstName&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc`

This is for Server Side sorting for a Spring Data Rest project.  Currently the Sorting portion is showing up as an array.  How do you change the way the sorting URL is formed?

Answer (score 0):

After a fair amount of coding by Google came up with this as a solution.  Please correct me if this is not correct.

Within KendoUI Grid you can modify a URL via the `parameterMap`. Below is how this will format the KendoUI URL to what Spring Data Rest is expecting.

```
<script>
    function parameterMap(data, operation) {
        if (operation == "read") {
            if (data.sort && data.sort.length > 0) {
                var p = {};
                if(!data.sort && data.sort.length < 0) {
                    p = data.page(1);
                } else {
                    p = data.page
                }
                var values = {};
                values["page"] =  p;
                values["size"] = data.pageSize;
                values["sort"] = data.sort[0]['field'] + ',' + data.sort[0]['dir'];
                return values;
            } else {
                var values = {};
                values["page"] = data.page;
                values["size"] = data.pageSize;
                return values;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `else` portion will ensure that pagination will still work.  Also setting `values["page"] = p;` within the sorting portion ensures that when you sort it takes you to the 1st page of the sort.

The problem I still have is if you load the page then navigate to a page then hit sort it takes you to page 1 of the sorted data.  If you now navigate to another page in the sorted data set and then choose to sort again it will not take you to page one of the new sort.